# Why am I getting 30 draw calls from an empty GameObject in my scene in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

First of all, I'm talking about SetPass calls, which I understand are draw calls.

I have an empty GameObject that I use as a Camera target in my game. I've positioned it above my character and when it reaches x height the camera moves up.

With the Camera target enabled, I get about 60 SetPass calls. When I disable it, I get around 30.

Why does this simple object produce so many SetPass calls?

Here's the screenshot with empty GameObject enabled:

[image]

Here's the screenshot without GameObject enabled:

[image]

Here is the empty GameObject:

[image]

This is where I reference the empty GameObject(cameraTarget):

void FixedUpdate(){

```
if (cameraTarget != null){
    if (cameraTarget.transform.position.y > thisTransform.position.y) {
        thisTransform.position = new Vector3 (0, Mathf.SmoothDamp (thisTransform.position.y, cameraTarget.transform.position.y, ref velocity.y, smoothTime), 0); 
    }
}
```

}

When I disable the empty GameObject during gameplay my game runs fine and the camera still follows the empty GameObject even though it's disabled and I'm getting way less SetPass calls... weird.

EDIT:

The label icon attached to my Empty GameObject was causing the increase in draw calls:

[image]

EDIT:

I disabled the "Gizmos" in the Game window and it has removed draw calls across all of my scenes. I guess it's only an issue when running a game in the Editor.

Comment: this doesn't look to me like it's an empty object.... Your first example shows 736 Triangles, 1.1k Vertices; The second shows 512 Triangles, 802 Vertices.  Clearly there is something else in the scene.

Comment: @Claies - The GameObject is nested inside of my character

Comment: right, that still doesn't explain where the extra triangles/vertices are at, but those are surely what is causing more SetPass calls.

Comment: I updated my question to include a picture of the empty GameObject with just a Transform. This is the object I am disabling/enabling.

Comment: Is there any dynamic mesh creation code in your project? Is there any possibility that the Empty gameobject would be assigned to or used by any of dynamic mesh creation codes?

Comment: @Can Baycay - I don't think so, but I'm not familiar with dynamic mesh creation. I will update post to include the code that references the empty GameObject

Comment: There is a possibility that the reason might not be your camera. It would be other scripts that attached to other -unexpected- gameobjects in scene. Some scripts could screw up draw calls for wide variety of reasons. There is a good and quick practice. Make a backup of your scene and delete gameobjects step by step while keeping an eye on draw calls. Hopefully the gameobject that causes this dramatic gap will pop up if the cause was another gameobject.

Comment: You should rather ask what you can do to reduce the draw calls. You have multiple characters in your project. Make sure their texture is packed in an atlas and they use the same material or have shared material. Keep your characters low poly and you will lower you draw calls count. FYI, 100+ draw calls are easy for mobile phones to handle. Of course don't go for 1000+ draw calls even though that will be handled too. That empty game object has barely anything to do with draw calls count. If it isn't being rendered, it doesn't participate in incrementing the draw call count.

Comment: So I found the problem. It doesn't make any sense to me but it seems to have solved the issue. I removed the label icon from the GameObject in the inspector and now draw calls are back to 30. Can a label icon really produce 30 draw calls? Seems crazy to me.

Answer (score 1):

Unity 5 have a neat feature called Frame Debugger. You can capture the frame and see what is going on exactly, More informations here http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/07/29/frame-debugger-in-unity-5-0/